# How to set the title not display?

Tags: android

It can remove title by setting requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) in onCreat(). But the title display first, then disappear. How could the title not display? Could it set in manifest file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use like this in your manifest file:-

```
<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
```

Answer (score 1):

just permission in activity which u want to have no title

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this way..

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the default theme and no title, you can put this in your manifest file:

```
<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
```

You can also set it from the `Theme` drop-down menu above your layout in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use the `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` before using the `setContentView`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

}
```